# get_all_category_ids for bookmark

Tags: list, id, bookmark

I was wondering how to create a list of categories name and ids for Wordpress Bookmarks such as [`get_all_category_ids`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_all_category_ids) for post.

I tried using the [`get_bookmarks`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmarks), but the category does not appear in it.

**Update**:

Based on advice from @Mridul-Aggarwal, I wrote code that might be useful:

```
<?php
    $tautan=get_terms('link_category');//get links category object
    $html="<ul>\r\n";//Init

    /*Looping*/
    foreach($tautan as $isi) {
        $nama=$isi->name;
        $id=$isi->term_taxonomy_id;
        $html.="\t<li>$id - $nama</li>";
    };
    $html.="</ul>\r\n";

    /*Output*/
    echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: It is helpful to provide links for the functions you reference. Usually that means a link to the WordPress [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) or [PHP's docs](http://php.net/manual/en/). But anything that clarifies what you have tried or what you are doing could help.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: I wish so, but at the time, I do not understand how to type the code in the edit. :) BTW, thanks for your editing help.

Comment: those functions are all buttons above the edit screen or click the orange "?" on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about `get_terms('link_category');`?

Once you have the objects, you can use them to get whatever information you like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) or [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories). The latter will return an array that you can use to create and format links however your like.

Comment: But these only shows the category of the post, not bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

The function [get_bookmark()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bookmark/) exists, which also returns the category IDs in an array, for the ID of the bookmark passed.